# Initializing and using `sessionStorage` in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently trying to save an item into [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) before rendering occurs.

My code is something like this:

```js
  componentWillMount() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("isUserLogged", false);
  }
```

However, it says that "`sessionStorage` is not defined." How do I use `sessionStorage` in React before rendering occurs?

Comment: try window.sessionStorage.setItem("key" , "value");

Comment: @Kartik_Agarwal Just tried that, its now showing `window` is not defined

Comment: you are using server side rendring or client side?

Comment: Should be using server side

Comment: After rendering, I would be able to set my sessionStorage but I want to do it before rendering occurs.

Comment: try to use cookies instead of sessionStorage. i hope it will work in server side rendring

Comment: `document` is also undefined before rendering, so I can't use `document.cookie`. I want a way to store data (available to other components) before rendering but also without needing to install other node modules.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

SessionStorage is not available when using server side rendering (you can mock it but data won't be available to user).

It's available only in browser https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Example of writing to storage

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem("key", "value");
```

To retrieve item from storage use

```
window.sessionStorage.getItem("key");
```

Comment: This is an old question, but can you point out that sessionStorage will work when the component has mounted. That is the moment where `sessionStorage` will be defined.

Comment: The answer is correct that it's only available on the client side. However, to properly answer the above question, IMO the answer should indicate that you can leverage this in componentDidMount ... which happens after React component is fully client side. the pattern you'd use is initialize an state variable with a default setting and then update it with the session information once component is mounted.

Answer (score 3):

I was using next and used react effect to solve the problem, solved like this:

```
import React from 'react';

function Cookies() {
const [accepted, setAccepted] = React.useState(false);

React.useEffect(() => {
    if (window.sessionStorage.getItem('cookies')) {
        setAccepted(true);
    }
}, []);

function acceptPolicy() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('cookies', true);
    setAccepted(true);
}

return !accepted ? (
    <></>):(<></>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

The read-only sessionStorage property accesses a session Storage object for the current origin. sessionStorage is similar to localStorage; the difference is that while data in localStorage doesn't expire, data in sessionStorage is cleared when the page session ends.