# Cannot getItem from sessionStorage in ComponentWillMount?

Tags: javascript, session-storage

Just looking to pull in some data sitting in `sessionStorage` inside of `componentWillMount` but I continue running into: `cannot getItem of undefined`. Here is what this looks like:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log(window.sessionStorage); // logs sessionStorage
    console.log(window.sessionStorage.getItem('some-key')); // errors out here
  }
```

EDIT: Here is a screenshot. The key is different because I was just using something else for the example, but the error is the same.

[image]

Here is the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property "getItem" from undefined`. Odd enough, **it works in componentDidMount**.

For clarification: I'm using `window.sessionStorage` instead of `sessionStorage` because for some reason it can't recognize it without appending it to the `window` object.

Found one or two [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40399873/initiliaze-using-sessionstorage-in-react) on similar topics but nothing to help explain why `getItem` is not available on `sessionStorage`.

Comment: `window.sessionStorage` is defined?

Comment: @taha Yeah, comes up defined with all the proper key/value pairs.

Comment: Have you tried dropping the `window.` part and just using `sessionStorage`?

Comment: are you stringifying entries before storing them?

Comment: @taha That wouldn't account for this error.

Comment: @taha Yes. Entries are being stringified before being stored.

Comment: Are you sure `some-key` is being set?

Comment: @Matt Yes, see updated question. I added a screenshot.

Comment: Please paste here full error from the console, it may be helpful.

Comment: @hinok Updated with the error.

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to your component class(.ts file).

```
get sessionStorage() {
    return sessionStorage;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `sessionStorage` in `ComponentDidMount`.